# TFS 2012 Integration SharePoint 2013 Issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, tfs

Trying to do integration between TFS and SharePoint, but running into some issues.

Followed instruction as [this article](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2012/), with a small difference, TFS 2012 is sitting on one server, SharePoint 2013 is on a different server.

But when trying to add SharePoint Web Applications in TFS, **TF255329** error popped up as below:

> TF255329: The following site could not be accessed: `http://servername`. The server that you specified did not return the expected response. Either you have not installed the Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products on this server, or a firewall is blocking access to the specified site or the SharePoint Central Administration site. For more information, see the Microsoft Web site (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161206)

Is there any further setup to be done in SharePoint?

Comment: The question is answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328386/tfs-2012-integration-sharepoint-2013-issue/15348564#comment21709496_15348564

Comment: You should make it an answer so you get credit.  Also you might add that the troubleshooting guide found here deals with it as well, but basically says the same thing as the thread you posted.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggboer/archive/2010/02/25/sharepoint-integration-troubleshooting-guide.aspx

Comment: @Shawn, please post the link and the major steps as an answer so we can close this question

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a useless error message this one, but all is not lost.  I have wrestled with this one for about 2 weeks on and off, no support from Microsoft either.  I have now found the solution to our particular problem:

**PROBLEM:** Our SP far consists of 3 separate servers: 1x App Server & 2x Web Servers.  Instructions dictate that ALL SERVERS IN THE FARM MUST HAVE THE TFS Add-Ins INSTALLED.

This is true but there are semantics here.  You can install the TFS modules on each of the servers but when configuring the Web Servers, the TF255329 error shows up without a great deal of direction.

**SOLUTION:** Install the TFS modules on the APP SERVER FIRST.  Run the configuration after Reboot and confirm modules install correctly.  You will need to add the SP service accounts to the TFS host server for connection yada-yada-yada.

Next, install/Configure the TFS module on each of the Web Servers in the farm.  Should be automatic configuration; although node 2 for me had to be manually configured.

Lastly, add your new SP Web App to the TFS Host server.